# What does "They don’t get to keep it" mean?

Tags: meaning

This is the complete quote:

Instead Judy moved to Israel, apprenticed under a prominent female Bible scholar, and became a beloved teacher. (She also married and had five children.) Did she ever have a moment when she considered abandoning Scripture? “Many,” she said. “But my answer has consistently been, ‘They don’t get to keep it.’”

I simply do not know what it means in this context and I am a native English speaker

Answer (score 4):

*Get to VERB* is an idiom meaning “have permission or the opportunity to *VERB*”.

But to understand just who here gets to keep what, you have to see this in context:

> In Jewish day school, [Judy Klitsner] was denied access to holy texts because of her gender. “When the boys would study Talmud, the girls were sent to learn sewing,” she said over lunch. “You’ll need those skills in a few years when you get married and have kids,” she was told.
>          Instead, Judy moved to Israel, apprenticed under a prominent female Bible scholar, and became a beloved teacher. (She also married and had five children.) Did she ever have a moment when she considered abandoning Scripture? “Many,” she said. “But my answer has consistently been, “They don’t get to keep it.”
>          —Bruce Feiler, [*The First Love Story*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ch2MDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT30&dq=%22Did+she+ever+have+a+moment+when+she+considered+abandoning+Scripture?%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBz8jFn5DTAhUB0YMKHdhvDsoQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Did%20she%20ever%20have%20a%20moment%20when%20she%20considered%20abandoning%20Scripture%3F%22&f=false)

That is, Ms. Klitsner asserted her right to read Scripture: it isn’t restricted to males, they don’t get to keep it to themselves.

Comment: I'd usually assume to ***abandon*** the holy texts of one's culture implies *to reject the teachings embodied by those texts*, but that wouldn't make much sense in OP's context. If she'd really rejected the teachings as "false", she'd hardly care that only men were allowed to study and interpret them. So I guess in context it must mean she never actually "doubted" Scripture - just that she sometimes considered devoting more attention to her own family rather than spending most of her time *teaching* Scripture to others. But didn't want to leave all that social power in the hands of patriarchs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes; I take it that *abandoning Scripture* means abandoning *the study of* Scripture.

Comment: Crucially, *in that context*. I only became interested here because without the full context (which we both obviously located simultaneously), I couldn't imagine who "they"" might be (the only plural referent in the cited text was her children, and I *really* couldn't make that work! :). But I was still thinking in terms of her losing her faith - right up until the point where I found out who they *really* were, so only that alternative interpretation made sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly my reaction.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed an odd construction.  However, if you think of the 'moments of consideration' as seperate entities, rather than something that recurs in Judy's mind, it makes a bit more sense.

"My increased responsibilities and duties may have stolen my adolescent fervor for life, but whenever I swung a leg over the motorcycle's seat and tightened my helmet strap, I realized that they didn't get to keep it."

Comment: +1, although, without knowing more about the context it's hard to say whether this is really the same usage as the OP's example.

Comment: The quote has been changed without licence.

Comment: The passage I quoted was my own - It happens every day I take the bike out.

Comment: I think most likely what the woman meant was that she wasn't prepared to *permanently* abandon Scripture, because that would imply leaving *only the Jewish **boys/men*** ("**they**") in control of religious matters. [The preceding paragraph](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=+%22she+ever+have+a+moment+when+she+considered+abandoning+Scripture%22) says that *in Jewish day school she was denied access to holy texts because of her gender* (which presumably she found galling in this day and age).

Comment: Indeed so.  I see @StoneyB has thus answered, also.

Comment: My suggestion is that although StoneyB's explanation was very helpful, it remains mostly unclear what is meant by ‘They don’t get to keep it.’